Angular Reactive forms - disabled attribute
I have HTML code with some disabled fields that have different conditions for mark a check-box as dissabled:
<!-- RECIPIENTS -->
<div class="row mb-4 mt-2">
    <div class="col-12" formArrayName="recipients">
        <label class="mb-2">{{ departmentsOfSystem.includes(role.toLowerCase()) ? 'Sistemas destinatarios:' : 'Equipos destinatarios:' }}</label>

        <div class="d-flex justify-content-start flex-wrap">
            <mat-checkbox
                *ngFor="let recipient of getRecipientsByRoleAndTeam(role)"
                class="mr-3"
                [name]="recipient?.id"
                [checked]="recipient.checked"
                [disabled]="(recipient.id === 'GCRG' && !isCdGSelected()) || getDisabledRecipient(recipient)"
                (change)="onChangeRecipientState($event)"
            >
                {{ recipient.description }}
            </mat-checkbox>
        </div>
        
        <div *ngIf="role.toLowerCase() == 'cdg'">
            <label class="mb-2 mt-2">Autovalidación: </label>
        
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-start flex-wrap">
                <mat-checkbox
                    *ngFor="let recipient of getRecipientsByRoleAndTeam(role, 'VALIDACION')"
                    class="mr-3"
                    [name]="recipient?.id"
                    [checked]="recipient.checked"
                    [disabled]="!isCdGRole() || !isCdGSelected() || getDisabledRecipient(recipient)"
                    (change)="onChangeRecipientState($event)"
                >
                    {{ recipient.description }}
                </mat-checkbox>
            </div>
        </div>                          
    </div>
</div>

The code works perfectly but I keep having the console message:
 It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form directive. If you set disabled to true
      when you set up this control in your component class, the disabled attribute will actually be set in the DOM for
      you. We recommend using this approach to avoid 'changed after checked' errors.
       
      Example: 
      form = new FormGroup({
        first: new FormControl({value: 'Nancy', disabled: true}, Validators.required),
        last: new FormControl('Drew', Validators.required)
      });

I tried the [attr.disabled] but the message keeps coming out or at some points the component stops working.
How can I handle this error and keep my code with the disabled attributes for the same FormArray?

please share a minimal reproducible example on stackblitz for checking the issue.

@jennifer yasmin Don't mind the other guy. The message you get explains that you are using [disabled]="..." which should be used for template-driven forms. Since you're using reactive forms, you should remove this [disabled]="..." and set disabled state through your formgroup in typescript. Not sure how to use data bindings there though

For new standard you need to enable/disable reactive form elements from component code.
Example:
this.myReactiveForm.get('name')?.disable();

So as result you need to capture changes into a function and that function should enable/disable particular element of your reactive form.
Rough example:
changeHappen(elementName: string): void {
  if (needToDisable) {
    this.myForm.get(elementName)?.disable();
  } else {
    this.myForm.get(elementName)?.enable();
  }
}

Extra references:
https://v17.angular.io/api/forms/FormControl

To access a field in the form to disable you can code like this: this.form.controls.myField.disable();. And the same for enable this.form.controls.myField.enable();

As an option yes. I showed an example with string param in the method, so author can pass through his component name inside his ngFor.

There're a lot of "disabledControl" directives (the answer of Marcel show one of them from NetBasal.
@Directive({
  selector:'[disabledControl]',
  standalone:true

})
export class DisabledDirective
{
  @Input('disabledControl') set _(value:boolean)
  {
    this.control && this.control.control && this.control.control[value?'disable':'enable']()
  }
  constructor(@Optional() private control:NgControl){}
}

Nowadays, we can use the new signal and input
@Directive({
  selector:'[disabledControl]',
  standalone:true
})
export class DisabledDirective
{
  disabledControl = input<boolean>(false);
  constructor(@Optional() private control:NgControl){
    effect(() =>this.control && this.control.control && 
                this.control.control[this.disabledControl()?'disable':'enable']())
  }
}

You import the directive and use it, e.g. this stackblitz

As others already explained, the [disabled] directive you are using is not the optimal use for reactive forms. You can disable a control on creating with the disabled parameter or by using disable() and enable() methods.
You can find an interesting approach by Netanel Basal here: https://netbasal.com/disabling-form-controls-when-working-with-reactive-forms-in-angular-549dd7b42110
